# Displaying ASCII Value for RAND Char

Tags: c, ascii

I am displaying **Random** and **Unique** Characters in an array which I have done using the code provided at the end.

- I am generating 26 random letters with ASCII values from 65 to 90 and storing in an array.
- I am then generating a random letter and cross checking with each element already present in the array to check for uniqueness.

I know this is very inefficient, however this is not an issue in my case.

*My problem is: **How to display the ASCII value for each random character?***
I am used to displaying the ASCII value by using:

`printf("ASCII value of %c = %d\n", c, c);`

However since my letters are stored in `array[y]` I have been unable to do so successfully.

My code is:

```
{
    int array[26];
    int x, y;
    int count;
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (count = 0; count < 26; count++)
    {
        array[count] = rand() % 26 + 65;
    }

    while (i < 26) {
        c = rand() % 26 + 65;

        for (x = 0; x < i; x++)
        {
            if (array[x] == c) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (x == i) {
            array[i++] = c;
        }
    }
    for (y = 0; y < 26; y++) {
        printf(" %c = %d\n", array[y], c);
    }

    scanf_s("%d");
    return 0;  
}
```

1. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dD2D.png) linked
2. Randomness/Uniqueness working
3. ASCII value only of last letter to be generated

Comment: `printf(" %c = %d\n", array[y], array[y]);`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `array[y]`:

```
printf(" %c = %d\n", array[y], array[y]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, to fix your issue, you'd write `printf(" %c = %d\n", array[y], array[y])`  instead of `printf(" %c = %d\n", array[y], c)`.

Second, if you are storing letters, I'd suggest to declare the members of `array` as characters, too, i.e. use `char array[26]` instead of `int array[26]`.
BTW: if you declare it as `char array[27]` and somewhere set `array[26] = '\0'`, you can print out `array` directly, e.g. with `printf("my letters: %s",array)`